# Can Drush 9 be used with this core version?

Tags: 7, drush

I have a Drupal 7 site that was not built with Composer. I have been using Drush 7 with it, but about a week ago, `drush wd-show --tail` stopped working, I'm not getting any output. I installed Drush 9, but I'm having difficulty configuring it.

I created an XML file, per the example., Instructions say to put aliases in `$PROJECT/drush/sites/self.site.yml` but I don't have a project root with a `composer.json` – can I get this to work without using Composer to build my site? Or is Drush 9 depending on the Drupal site using Composer?

I'm running the local version of the site in MAMP on my Mac. I created `sites/drush/sites/self.site.yml` – it contains:

```
local:
  root: /Users/pglatz/dev/wdocs/wdocs-code/www
  uri: 'https://www.whiskerdocs-local-qa.pglatz.com/'
```

The command I'm using is:

```
$ drush9 @local --alias-path=/Users/pglatz/dev/wdocs/wdocs-code/www/sites/drush/sites --root=/Users/pglatz/dev/wdocs/wdocs-code/www
```

When I run it, I get the error:

> Command wd-show was not found. Pass --root or a @siteAlias in order to run Drupal-specific commands.

But I am passing `--root` and a site alias. Likely a dumb syntax error on my part, but I can't figure it out. What am I doing wrong? And how can I get Drush to be working properly again?

Answer (score 1):

No. Drupal 7 requires Drush 8.

[image]

See https://www.drush.org/latest/install/#drupal-compatibility

---

Furthermore, Drush 9 can't be installed globally.

[image]

See https://www.drush.org/latest/install/

Comment: it seems that this information is outdated ? https://docs.drush.org/en/7.x/install/#pick-a-version There is says that Drush 9 is compatible with D7/D8. Or are the docs mistaken probably ? Because indeed I could not get Drush 9 work with D7 ;-)

Comment: @Kojo – The docs you are linking to are outdated. See https://www.drush.org/latest/install/ for the latest. I probably should update the links in my answer as well.

Comment: Oh thanks. I'm wondering why drush maintainers then don't redirect to the new docs instead of leaving wrong things around ;-)